# Suppress log level config change messages in logback

Tags: logging, logback, logback-classic

When logback reads its config it outputs messages for every log level setting:

```
11:36:36,467 INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn] to ERROR
11:36:36,467 INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@2f465398 - Propagating ERROR level on Logger[org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn] onto the JUL framework
11:36:36,467 INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.redacted.config] to WARN
11:36:36,467 INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@2f465398 - Propagating WARN level on Logger[com.redacted.config] onto the JUL framework
```

Unfortunatley our (somewhat crude) alerting system picks up these ERRORs and WARNs.  (We can't safely tighten this up because we might miss issues from processes with badly configured log patterns)

Is there a way to suppress these level change messages?
Setting the log level for ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction and ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator to OFF or ERROR seems to have no effect.

We're using logback-classic along with jul-to-slf4j, log4j-over-slf4j and jcl-over-slf4j plus enabling the SLF4JBridgeHandler to pick up logging from the various different 3rd party libraries we use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have debugging enabled in the logback.xml file (`<configuration debug=“true”>…</configuration>`)? Or, more likely, there are multiple configurations on the classpath. Looking further up your console output do you see something like this:

> Resource […] occurs multiple times on the classpath

If so, then removing the ‘extra’ logback.xml, logback-test.xml files will result in logback **not** emitting those unwanted log events.

FWIW, Setting the log level for `ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction and ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator` to OFF or ERROR will have no effect because those log events are coming from logback’s internal logging which is not controlled by your logback configuration.

Comment: I do have debug="true" but this isn't causing the troublesome output.  The correct configuration is definitely being used.  As you say following the code I can see that the log level for these classes is ignored.

Comment: I think the likeliest explanaiton is that you have multiple configurations on your classpath. leaving aside the root cause, have you prevented Logback from emitting this events by setting the log level for ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction and ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator to OFF/ERROR?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a setting in the pod that overrode the config in the yaml files. Someone else was packaging the app so I didn't realise that they had added that setting.

Perhaps someone has set environment variables that you are unaware of?